# How do I remove extra space above and below the imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-image

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/program_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/borders"
        android:shadowColor="@color/light_grey"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/entertainment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/program_description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/borders"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/program_times"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/borders"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/program_episodes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WATCH EPISODES" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/program_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD TO CALENDAR" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my code when i run this it shows extra space above and below the imageview i'm stuck in this how to remove it.
It shows perfect on eclipse layout graphical view but shows extra space in emulator and android phone.

Comment: Show us the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your TextView's below and above the ImageView has padding:

```
android:padding="@dimen/borders"
```

try it without the padding, also notice that you image source might contain padding itself

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```